# Objective-C iOS 10 Data argument not used by format string when using NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsuserdefaults

I have working codes for iOS 8 when I want to convert it to Xcode 8 gives me that lines warning

> Data argument not used by format string

My codes clear why giving this warning ?

```
 NSString *name1 =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"name1"];
    NSString *name2 =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"name2"];
    username  =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"", name1,name2];
```

Where I can mistake ?

Comment: `%@%@` => Two arguments, `@""` counts as one, `name1` counts as one, `name2` counts as one. So It's waiting for 2 arguments, and you put 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are passing 3 argument instead of 2, by mistake or accidentally you have added `@""` as first formate specifier, so here `name2` is extra argument for format specifier that is the reason you are getting this warning.

**It's should be:**

```
username  =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", name1,name2];
```

**Instead of**

```
username  =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"", name1,name2];
```

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper Welcome mate :)